# convert double to a printf's %g-like string with minimal length without losing any precision

Tags: c, printf

I want to print double to C string with sufficient precision to recover the original number, but with the minimal length of the output string.

I can try something like this which maintains the precision. But the output string is too long.

What is an efficient way (better than trial and error as in the discussion) to return the minimal length string?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%1.*e\n", __DBL_DECIMAL_DIG__ - 1, 1.); // print 1.0000000000000000e+00. I want just "1."
    printf("%1.*e\n", __DBL_DECIMAL_DIG__ - 1, 1.00000001); // print 1.0000000099999999e+00. I want just "1.00000001"
    return 0;
}
```

The string representation is not necessarily the same as the original double. The string has to be of the minimal length.

Only the printf's %g like string format is allowed. printf's %a is not what I am looking for.

Unnecessary digits must be removed as long as when it does not affect the converted double value. For example, For `double x = 0.010`, x converted to string must be `.01`. For `double x = 1.0`, x converted to string must be `1.`.

One simply implementation is this. But I'd expect something more efficient rather than trial and error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *d2s(double x) {
    char format[100];
    static char buf[100];
    double y;
    int i = 0;
    while(1) {
        sprintf(format, "%%.%dg", i++);
        sprintf(buf, format, x);
        y = atof(buf);
        if(x == y) {
            return buf;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    double x = 11111.1111111;
    printf("%s\n", d2s(x)); // print "11111.1111111" as wanted.
    return 0;
}
```

Note that there are bugs in the above code. For example, `1.` is printed as `1`. Something better is needed.

Comment: You do know that not all values can be represented using floating point data types in C? In short, you want the "original" value `1.00000001` but there simply isn't such a value possible.

Comment: No. I want the minimal string representation of the original double value. The string representation is not necessarily exact. But if it is converted back to double, it should be the same as the original double.

Comment: `1.00000001` is not exactly representible as double. By definition there is no procedure to "recover" what source code you originally used, and was rounded to the nearest representible value

Comment: As I explained, I don't need the exact original value. I just need to get the value stored in the double with the minimum string length.

Comment: But the compiler and the `printf` function don't know what "minimum string length" might be... All `printf` knows is the precision you provided. If doing this with a variable with a run-time value, then it's really *impossible* to say what the "minimum string length" should be. Especially considering the representation and rounding problems of floating point values.

Comment: Any solution is fine. Nobody said it has to be done by the compiler.

Comment: If *any solution* is fine, then you can do this: start with precision 0; sprintf the number with that precision into a temporary buffer, and then sscanf it back into a double. If that's not the same double as you started with, increment the precision and repeat. If you're paranoid, stop when you reach DBL_DECIMAL_DIGIT + 1 and file a bug with the standard library implementation. If you can't prove that the number won't be a NaN, before you do any of the above start by calling isnan(); if it returns true, output whatever you think is appropriate for a NaN.

Comment: It has to be most efficient. I am not sure a trial and error way is most efficient. A solution that is aware of the current printf implementation may be needed.

Comment: It's clearly not the most efficient for a particular implementation of printf you're using. But you didn't say anything about efficiency before I provided that solution, which makes it a requirement change subject to an additional fee :-) (and requirements should go into the question, not a comment). Although it was a bit tongue-in-cheek, I don't know if you can find anything much better; binary search might be better (depending on the distribution of the numbers you're printing). I have to say that when I'm intent on round-tripping doubles, I use `%a`. But that's a different question.

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: This is explained again and again. See discussion.

Comment: What makes you think that it is possible?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which uses values stored in a double (as opposed a literal which first gets squeezed into a double). Otherwise your code does not match your description "print double to C string". Your current code would match "store a literal in a double, then print to string". That in turn, as has been mentioned in comments, is not possible for all literals, even not for those with few decimal places.

Comment: Or change the shown MRE to one which only uses literals that can be printed as the literal looks.

Comment: consider using hexadecimal floats (e.g. `0x0.3p10`), they can be stringified  without any loss of precision

Comment: One way could be to `sprintf()` with the maximum number of decimals, and then scan from the end to suppress zeroes. But as already commented, this works only for certain cases due to the common binary representation of floating point values. -- So, in general, it is not possible as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You may check out the function `dtoa_r` in http://www.netlib.org/fp/dtoa.c. Be warned, the code is massively complex. If I were to roll out my own convertor, I'd use your example function. To ensure `1.` is output with decimal point, insert `#` in the specifier (so it becomes `%%#.%dg`).

Answer (score -2):

> to recover the original number

C language is a language without [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming) - it can't inspect it's own source code. What was in the source code is not visible in the executable - as in, you can't recover the source code of a program by inspecting the executable.

In the case of a floating-point constants, the value is *converted* to the internal representation when compiling the program ([C11 6.4.4.2p5](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.2p5)), so the value of a floating-point constant is rounded to the nearest representable value, smaller or larger, then the actual value ([C11 J.3.6](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.3.6) `How the nearest representable...`). Most probably in your code on your platform `1.00000001` can't be represented exactly as `double`, so the value `1.00000001` never exists in the resulting executable and it's not possible to recover it from the executable in any way.

The only way to recover `1.00000001` is to inspect the source code of your own program - you can write your own build system for that and write your own parser for that. The other way you could use is to use processor `#` operator to stringify the argument and specify the constant twice:

```
#define STRING(x) #x
printf("%s is converted to %a\n", STRING(1.00000001), 1.00000001);
```

Comment: This is not relevant. See my updated minimal code. It can be done at runtime. But I need something more efficient. Please vote to reopen the question.

Comment: `This is not relevant.` You stated that you want to recover the number `with sufficient precision to recover the original number`. That is not possible, the number `1.00000001` is rounded down and never gets to the executable. To recover the number as the original number, you have to inspect the source code. `I want the minimal string representation of the original double value` Then use `%a`.

Comment: `I need something more efficient` Try your function code with `double x = 11111.111111100000001;`, it does not work. But, anyway, write your own float->string conversion function that will adhere to the requirements that you laid out.  `What is an efficient way (better than trial and error as in the discussion) to return the minimal length string?` Roll your own strfromf function.